# Selenium to load web page at server side without chrome browser

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

i want to make selenium to work at the server side for scraping data. Will the selenium chrome driver work without chrome browser gui in ubuntu server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it would work. But it has to be in headless mode. But GUI mode it wouldn't work.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path, options = options)
```